# Understanding Java memory model during context switches

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Recently in a conference talk the following was used as an example to demonstrate the Java memory model in a multithreaded environment.

```
public class A {

    public static boolean done;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        done = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("running...");

                int count = 0;
                while (!done) {
                    count++;
                }

                System.out.println("Exiting thread");
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("in main...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println("setting done to true");
        done = true;
    }
}
```

I understand that the new thread created in above code will never exit because of `done` variable being cached in Thread's local cache. And a proper solution will be to make the `done` variable volatile.

But if inside the while loop, we call `Thread.sleep()` as follows

```
    while (!done) {
        count++;
        try {Thread.sleep(0);} catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

then the Thread successfully exits.

My understanding is that because of `sleep(0)` a context switch will occur that will invalidate the cache entries, so each time the updated value of `done` is retrieved. Is my understanding correct? Also is this behaviour dependent on the number of cores of the machine?

Comment: It **can** happen that the thread never finishes *or it might*. That's the point: within the memory model you have no guarantee one way or another. Some specific actions may cause `done` to be re-read from main memory, but that's entirely implementation-dependent (outside of course of the specified read-barriers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Java Language Specification** clearly states that `Thread::sleep` does not have any **happens-before** semantics (and those are the only one you want to reason with):

> ... Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield have any synchronization semantics...

As such whatever output you "happen" to see using it, are not guaranteed by the specification. The only guarantees you have is when done *is* `volatile`, again, because the **JLS** gives you such guarantees.

Your reasoning about a correctly synchronized program must be backed against **happens-before**, context switch, caches, etc. are irrelevant.

Comment: By saying context switch and caches are irrelevant in the given scenario, do you mean it's implementation dependent so one should not rely on it or do you mean it's completely unrelated to the topic in discussion?

Comment: @JavaLearner the first one.